# How to make the user type a value instead of storing a constant value?

Tags: c++

I have made a simple program in C++ and this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int number;
    int square;

    number = 5;
    square = number * number;
    cout << "The square is ";
    cout << square;

    return 0;
}
```

what it does is basically taking the integer "5" and get the square value on the screen and so on...

my question is:

how can I make the program take any value from the user instead of storing a value in the memory?

than Q.

Comment: You should continue on reading your book.

Answer (score 4):

Your code makes use of `cout` to print. C++ makes `cin` available for input from the console:

```
int x;
cin >> x;
```

Comment: thank you. now I know the meaning of cout and its opposite cin

Answer (score 3):

**"An example is worth a thousand words..."**

Well `cout` takes some var. from memory and prints it out on the screen, right? 
Well, `cin` does the exact opposite, it takes in some value from the keyboard and puts it in your memory..

You have to take in the value with the help of `cin` command, like this:

```
int a; //lets say you have a variable
cout << "Enter a value here: "; //prompts the user to enter some number 
cin >> a; //this line will allow the user to enter some value with the keyboard into this var.
int square = a * a;
cout << "The square is: " <<  square;
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: @user2624929 the best way of appreciating answers in to accept them, bro :)

Answer (score 2):

Just replace:

```
number = 5;
```

with:

```
cout << "What's the number? ";
cin >> number;
```

You already know how to use `cout` to generate output, this simply uses `cin` to retrieve input.

Keep in mind that, while this may be okay for small test programs or learning, data input in real programs tends to be a little more robust (such as if you enter the string `xyzzy` when it's trying to input an `int` variable).

Comment: thank you, but are saying that it gets more complicated when building a bigger program, or it there will be another coding technique other than     cin and     cout

Comment: @user2624929, I'm saying that if you enter `xyzzy`, the result will not be what you expect from a robust program. A robust program would output an error like `"That's not a number, you goose!"` and then ask again, rather than continuing with dodgy data. You can still use cin but there are extra checks you would do.